# partial derivatives of Scipy smooth spline not working

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I tried to take the second x derivative of a fitted smooth spline in Scipy, like following:

```
spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,kx=3,ky=1)
splinedxx = spline.partial_derivative(2,0)
```

This give me following error:

```
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack2.py", line 988, in partial_derivative
newc, ier = dfitpack.pardtc(tx, ty, c, kx, ky, dx, dy)
dfitpack.error: ((0 <= nuy) && (nux < ky)) failed for 7th argument nuy: pardtc:nuy=0
```

The same error is given when I try the first derivative. What did I do wrong? Or is it something caused by my data?

Answer (score 1):

set `ky=3` solves the problem. It seems like the order of y also need to be greater than the order of differentiation on x.